How to correctly save a fine tuned model using apple MLX framework
We're using MLX to fine tune a model fetched from hugging face.
from transformers import AutoModel
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('deepseek-ai/deepseek-coder-6.7b-instruct')

We fine tuned the model with command like python -m mlx_lm.lora --config lora_config.yaml and the config file looks like:
# The path to the local model directory or Hugging Face repo.
model: "deepseek-ai/deepseek-coder-6.7b-instruct"
# Save/load path for the trained adapter weights.
adapter_path: "adapters"

When the adapter files generated after fine tuning, we evaluated the model by scripts like
from mlx_lm.utils import *
model,tokenizer = load(path_or_hf_repo ="deepseek-ai/deepseek-coder-6.7b-instruct",
                      adapter_path = "adapters" # path to new trained adaptor
                      )
text = "Tell sth about New York"
response = generate(model, tokenizer, prompt=text, verbose=True, temp=0.01, max_tokens=100)

and it works as expected.
However, after we saved the model and evaluated with mlx_lm.generate, the model worked poor. (the behavior is completely different from invoking the model with generate(model, tokenizer, prompt=text, verbose=True, temp=0.01, max_tokens=100).
mlx_lm.fuse  --model "deepseek-ai/deepseek-coder-6.7b-instruct" --adapter-path "adapters" --save-path new_model
mlx_lm.generate --model new_model --prompt "Tell sth about New York" --adapter-path "adapters" --temp 0.01


Once you fuse the model you don't want to specify the adapter path otherwise it will try to add adapters to an already fused model (which is a bug).
Try using:
mlx_lm.generate --model new_model --prompt "Tell sth about New York" --temp 0.01

Also fusing can cause some degradation. The adapted weights are: W = W + scale * b^T a. When you fuse b^T a into W it can be destructive if the adapter (b^T a) has very different magnitude than the base weights (W), particularly when using quantized or low precision base weights.
Tuning the scale parameter can improve the model performance after fusion.

Yes that's the root cause of the issue, found it right after the question submitted. Thanks for your further explanation about the underneath.
